# How to get a file's manufacturer name

Tags: batch-file

I need to realize the following algorithm in a Windows 10 batch file.

- Loop through a directory and search for files.
- For each file found, get its manufacturer's name.
- If the manufacturer's name is for example "Microsoft", delete the file.

I've already made some tries with a FOR loop and the WMIC DATAFILE without any success; I just can't get the manufacturer's name into a variable for comparison.

I use the following code to loop through all the files (and directories):

```
pushd C:\<path>\Temp

for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /a /b') do (<something_with_%%F>)

popd
```

Then, I use the following code to get a file's manufacturer name:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\<path>\\Temp\\<file_name>.<ext>" get manufacturer
```

This preceding code will output (if used with the "echo" command) the following (if the target file belongs to Microsoft):

```
Manufacturer
Microsoft
```

Now, the problems begin when I try to use those two pieces of code together to realize the algorithm (pseudo-code) described above. Unless there's another way to do this?

Comment: Attach your work and then get help.

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44105143/edit) and show us your work

Comment: I do not quite get the manufacturer part. where exactly do you see this attribute in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to piece those two codes together, there is functionality buit in to the `WMIC` command.

For Example:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('
    "WMIC DataFile Where (Drive='C:' And Path='\\<path>\\Temp\\' And Not Manufacturer Is Null) Get FileName, Manufacturer, Version"
') Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Echo(%%B
```

You will obviously need to replace `\\<path>\\Temp\\` with your true path, *(must begin and end with \\)*.

You could even target only exe files by adding `And Extension='exe'` to your `Where` block.